# How can I modify the below code in order to by a specific field name from a JsonBMap type in JPA?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa

so i am trying to sort asc/desc from a JsonBMap in JPA, which i can easily do in my Postgres console:

```
select e from employee e
         where data->'loan'->>'type' LIKE '%Car%'
order by data->'loan'->>'type' asc
```

Please note that data is my JsonB map name and here's the code I am using to do the ordering:

```
private static void setOrderBy(Collection<String> orderBys, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, From root, Map<String, Map<String, String>> jsonBMap) {
        final List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
        var mapName = jsonBMap.keySet().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
        var map = jsonBMap.get(mapName);

        orderBys.stream()
                .map(field -> {
                    var isFieldDesc = field.startsWith("-");
                    var fieldWithoutSign = isFieldDesc ? field.substring(1) : field;

                    if (map.get(fieldWithoutSign) != null) {
                        var value = map.get(fieldWithoutSign);
                        Expression<?>[] expressions = Stream.of(List.of(root.get(mapName)), getExpressions(value, criteriaBuilder))
                                .flatMap(List::stream)
                                .toArray(Expression<?>[]::new);
                        Expression<String> expression = criteriaBuilder.function("jsonb_extract_path_text", String.class, expressions);
                        return isFieldDesc ? criteriaBuilder.desc(expression) : criteriaBuilder.asc(expression);
                    } else {
                        String[] explodedPath = fieldWithoutSign.split("\\.");
                        Path<?> selection = explodedPathAsPath(root, explodedPath);
                        return isFieldDesc ? criteriaBuilder.desc(selection) : criteriaBuilder.asc(selection);
                    }
                }).forEach(orders::add);

        criteriaQuery.orderBy(orders);
    }
```

Kindly note that I have even added the configuration to register the function below in my Postgres Config

```
 registerFunction("jsonb_extract_path_text", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StringType.INSTANCE, "jsonb_extract_path_text(?1, ?2, ?3)"));
```

After executing:

```
criteriaQuery.multiselect(List.of(mainObject,order.getExpression));
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
return query.getResultStream();
```

The **query.getResultStream()** is throwing the error below:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
  Position: 739
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2505)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2241)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:447)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:368)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:158)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:108)
    at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
```

Can you please advise?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the columns used in the ORDER BY aren't specified in the DISTINCT refer to this [post](https://blog.jooq.org/how-sql-distinct-and-order-by-are-related/). If you try to run this, it will raise the same error.

```
select distinct e 
from employee e
where data->'loan'->>'type' LIKE '%Car%'
order by data->'loan'->>'type' asc
```

To tackle this you can remove `distinct QueryHint` in query.

If you still need to order let's add it into your select

```
select distinct e, data->'loan'->>'type' as loan_type
from employee e
where data->'loan'->>'type' LIKE '%Car%'
order by data->'loan'->>'type' asc
```